# How to find the top 10 countries with the highest suicide rate (suicides/100k pop) from this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a suicide data of 100 countries from year 1985-2016.
It has a column which contains, suicides/100k pop, which is basically suicide rate.
But the problem is that the data is divided in each year and then further in age groups and gender.
I want the overall top 10 countries with the highest suicides/100k pop.
I have attached a preview of the table.

I am not able to build a query since the data is divided for each year you can't sum the suicide rate for each year to find the overall suicide rate.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to build the average of the suicides column and group by country

Comment: Since the `suicides/100k pop` column is already aggregated you won't be able to do anything useful with it (e.g.: you can't add them up to get a total). You'll probably need to group by country and year and calculate the overall value from somthing like `sum(sucides)/sum(population/100000.0)`.

Comment: ```select country,year,suicides_no/(population/100000.0) as 'suicides/100k pop' FROM (
(select country,year,sum(suicides_no) suicides_no, sum(population) population from yourtable
group by country,year) a
order by  suicides_no/(population/100000.0) desc```